# how to find index of array element by the name of it inside a function?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a js function that reads a JSON file and outputs them with a loop :

```
response.data.forEach((item,index)=>{

  items += " <div class='eleman'>"
        + "<img src='"+item.teamMember.profileImageUrl+"' width='100%'>"
        + "<div class='content list'>"
        + "<div class='fullname'>"+item.teamMember.fullName+"</div>"+

    ...
```

There is an array on that json called customFields (item.teamMember.customFields) and it could have 0 to 7 indexes, example for one of them should be like :

```
id    : 1202
name  : Tags
type  : SingleLineText
value : Composer,Music,Pan's Labyrinth
```

I want to get the value of the index that's name is ByLine. And use it under the full name div.

I tried several codes but they didn't work. Would appreciate if anyone can help.

Comment: May we look at the structure of each element of the array `item.teamMember.customFields`?

Comment: Please make the question a lttle more clear by adding wht you are trying to achieve? Make the problem reproduced with the code snippet.

Comment: @jsN00b I already shared that, the second code block

Comment: @Nitheesh I think its' clear what I want to achieve. I want to get the array element that's "name" is "ByLine" within the array called  item.teamMember.customFields

Comment: @MrB why you cant simply make use of `response.data.filter(item => item.name === "ByLine")`?

Answer (score 2):

Below are assumed from the question:

1. `response.data` is an Array
2. Each element in this Array is an object
3. Each such object has a prop named `teamMember`
4. Each `teamMember` has a prop named `customFields` which is an Array
5. Each element of the Array (at point 4 above) has a prop `name`

The objective is to filter only those elments from `customFields` array where the element's `name` prop matches the value `ByLine`.

One possible way to achieve this:

```
const getIndexOfByLine = (arr = item.teamMember.customFields, matchNameWith = 'ByLine') => (
  arr
    .map((el, i) => ({elt: el, idx: i}))
    .filter(obj => obj.name === matchNameWith)
    .map(obj => obj.idx)
    [0]
);
```

NOTE: If more than 1 element has `name` as 'ByLine' then only the first index is returned.

**Explanation**

- Iterate through the `item.teamMember.customFields` array using `map` with element as `el` and index as `i`.
- For each element in the array, return an object with two props namely`elt` and `idx`

`.map((el, i) => ({elt: el, idx: i}))`

- In the resulting array, apply the filter and keep only those elements where `name` matches `ByLine` (can be changed via parameter `matchNameWith`)

`.filter(obj => obj.name === matchNameWith)`

- Now, we have an array with objects that have the two props `elt` and `idx`. Since we only require the index, `map` the array to get only the index.

`.map(obj => obj.idx)`

- In case there were more than 1 elements that had 'ByLine' as the `name`, simply use the first occurance.

`[0]`

Answer (score 0):

I used this and it worked

```
let byline=item.teamMember.customFields.filter(checkbyline);


function checkbyline(fields) {
  if (fields.name == 'Byline') {
  return fields.value}
else {return }
}
```

and to use it on the HTML output

```
byline[0].value
```